# How to pause input when using Thread.sleep in Java

Tags: java

When I pause the execution in my program with `Thread.sleep`, it seems that the program is still able to get input, even while it is being paused. Is there any fix to this? I am using Java 2 and I've looked through so many forums, but couldn't find a suitable answer.

This is the code I'm using to pause my program:

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
int input = c.readInt();
```

Comment: this question seems a bit broad... let's try to clarify some points. What is exactly a pause in your application, and how long do you want your program to pause for?

Comment: There seems to be some confusion. In the code snippet above, the call to `c.readInt()` will not happen until after 2 seconds elapse. Please provide more details on the results you are seeing that seem to indicate the input is happening before the sleep completes.

Comment: I looks like you are typing in the terminal, but this input will be passed to java code after 2 seconds. 

Also you need to share more details. How do you know that program is getting input? Could you share the complete program and the steps you took.

Answer (score 4):

Your program does not control the terminal device. You can see what you type because the software that actually controls the device is reading keyboard input and writing it to the screen. *Your* program is not getting any input while it's in sleep.

What actually controls the terminal window or device depend on operating system, and things get complicated when dive into the details. For example on Unix, it's handled by a a thing called "line discipline". The default ("canonical") setting lets you edit lines of text before they are sent to your programs. It also intercepts key combinations like control-c and control-z for job control. Further reading: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_terminal_interface